# Performing model method in after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to send an welcome email in a rails application after a user signs up. Currently I have a redirection that will take them to a specific page. I have a mailer method that I want to send but it doesn't work. Is there another way to do this?

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if current_user
    ModelMailer.new_user_notification(@user).deliver
    '/dashboard'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send the email in the user model, with a simple after_create:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
   # ...

   after_create: send_welcome_email

   def send_welcome_email
     ModelMailer.new_user_notification(self).deliver
   end
end
```

Comment: And this is exactly what I did! Thanks